# 5000 рублей/рублями?

Tags: управление

Как правильно написать «выразившееся в мошенничестве, связанном с завладением 5000 рублей/рублями»?

Comment: Образец употребления (Нацкорпус) :

>неизвестный. Вести, «Русское слово», 1907 **Схватив мешок с двумя тысячами рублей,** неизвестные, не обратив внимания на другой мешок, в котором лежало 15 тысяч рублей, скрылись.
Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы. За этим первым письмом последовало на другой день второе, в котором пан Муссялович просил ссудить его **двумя тысячами рублей** на самый короткий срок. 
Вельтман. (1848) Быть медиком при моих именьях, **с двумя тысячами рублей жалованья.**
Крылов. (1792) ...наградил он его своим родительским благословлением и **двумя тысячами рублей на дорогу.**

Answer (score 13):

Количественные числительные  согласуются с сущ. в косвенных падежах.Однако тысяча(как и миллион, миллиард) - существительное и сочетается как существительное - т.е. управляет существительным.Согласование возможно только в том случае, если слово тысяча обозначает точное число и не имеет при себе определения: с тысячью студентами, с тысячью знакомыми, с тысячью рублями в кармане.У нас же есть определение:...с завладением чем? тысячами рублей(слитное словосоч.)сколькими? пятью. В слитном сочетании сущ.+сущ. связь управление: тысячами чего?-рублей.

Comment: +9!!! Осталось принять правильный и лаконичный ответ.

Comment: Особенно после того, как смысл его был изменен на противополозный. 
(Людмила, это не Вам)

Answer (score 5):

Дамы и господа, призываю вас не решать вопросы правильности речи голосованием "кто больше минусов поставит". 
Это вообще неприемлемый путь, а тут ещё излишне ранимые авторы...
Минусить, имхо, надо за откровенный флуд, троллинг и нежелание корректно отстаивать свою позицию. А тут вопрос весьма неочевидный, можно и нужно спорить...

Правильный вариант: "Пятью тысячами рублями". Норму эту пока никто не отменял. 
Я не комментирую непонятный источник по ссылке grumant'а, во всяком случае пока есть Розенталь и классики.

//----
~1. Равноправны вариантные формы тысячей – тысячью, но они предполагают разное последующее управление; ср.: расходы исчисляются не одной тысячей рублей (слово тысяча с предшествующим числительным одна рассматривается как существительное и управляет родительным падежом следующего слова) – приехал сюда с тысячью рублями (***в качестве числительного слово тысяча обычно согласуется с последующим существительным***); возможна также связь управления при форме тысячью, например: тысячью дорогих безделушек (Мамин-Сибиряк); тысячью буйных и огненных голосов (Л. Андреев); тысячью мелких уколов (Короленко); «Человек с тысячью лиц» (название кинофильма).
//----  
[Розенталь, Литературное редактирование текста](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm) 
(§166. Сочетания числительных с существительными, курсив мой - b-s).

"Нам надо средств-с, средств прежде всего, и вот, после долгих споров, порешено у него с отцом на последних шести тысячах рублях, и их ему высылают."  
(Достоевский, "Братья Карамазовы")

Тут был француз К. М., женатый
На кукле чахлой и горбатой
И семи тысячах душах.
(Пушкин "Евгений Онегин", 8, XXV)

и проч.

Очень кратко о причинах всей этой неразберихи (хотя тут можно километры исписать, но просто не располагаю сейчас временем).

По принципу согласования (пятью, десятью, ста, восьмьюстами, тысячью, двумя тысячами рублями, метрами, человеками) работают чительные до тысячи включительно, далее, начиная с миллиона - управление (миллионом, двумя миллионами, миллиадами рублей, метров, человек). На то есть исторические причины, классические числительные в русском языке имели свои правила согласования/управления, более поздние заимствования им уже не подчинялись.

Однако, в последнее время в разговорной речи наметилась тенденция относить числительные тысяча и производные к существительным-числительным типа миллион, а совсем недавно так же поступать еще и с числительными двести, триста ... девятьсот. Отсюда и современные формы "пятьюстами, девятьюстами, тысячей, двумя тысячами рублей" при нормативной ***рублями***.

Ситуация осложняется еще и тем, что само по себе слово тысяча имеет признаки как "старого", так и "нового" числительного и может употребляться как существительное в ряду десяток, сотня, тысяча (сабель, например), что усиливает тенденцию к использованию формы управления, а не согласования. Однако такое использование нормативным пока не признано.

Еще раз простите, тороплюсь, но мимо пройти не смог.

Дополню ссылками на дискуссии, ведущияся на грамоте (не претендую на полноту, их только на моей памяти было много больше)

http://www.gramota.ru/forum/veche/55044/
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=27&i=7936&t=7936
http://www.gramota.ru/forum/klass/116223/
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=27&i=1914&t=1892&v=f
http://www.gramota.ru/forum/spravka/74645/

И [вот](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%F2%FB%F1%FF%F7%E0%EC%E8+%F0%F3%E1%EB%FF%EC%E8) маленький шедевр от "Справки"

//----

Кстати, о старой-новой норме... Не такая уж она и новая:

Но сей великодушной человѣкъ, въ зрѣлыхъ лѣтахъ заплативъ глазомъ за открытіе истины въ спряженіяхъ, еще въ молодости лишился выгоднаго мѣста отъ усердія къ правильности склоненій. Мы въ другое свиданіе говорили съ нимъ объ именахъ числительныхъ: онъ доказывалъ, что наши Грамматики не даютъ вѣрнаго правила для сочиненія ихъ съ другими именами, и сказалъ: ,,Вы найдете въ Грамматикахъ, что надобно говорить: два человѣка, семь рублей: важное наставленіе! Кто изъ Рускихъ ошибается въ этомъ случаѣ? ***Но гдѣ же узнаете, какъ должно писать: съ двумя стами Гранадеръ или Гренадерами, съ двумя тысячами рублей или рублями?*** Вотъ камень преткновенія! вотъ узелъ Гордіевъ!...

([Карамзин](http://knigolubu.ru/russian_classic/karamzin_nm/stati_iz_vestnika_evropyi.6866/?page=23); курсив мой - b-s)

Comment: Насчёт классиков - это нормы 19 века.Язык меняется, синтаксические нормы очень изменились. Учёные до сих пор спорят о морфологии: тысяча - числительное или существительное.РГ-80 и Ожегов-Шведова считают только существительным, Евгеньева и Кузнецов сущ. называют  в значении "много", а точное количество - числительным. Кому верить - не знаю, по крайней мере изменяется как сущ.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Это современная норма.

Comment: > Завладел тремя миллионами рублей 
> Это современная норма.   

В свете борьбы с коррупцией получилось двусмысленно ))

Comment: >Насчёт классиков - это нормы 19 века.Язык меняется...

Это уже другой разговор. Если норма существовала, значит о полной неправильности речи уже идти не может. Но даже в этмо случае надо апокащзать, когда и почему норма изменилась. Но поскольку ни малейшего упоминания в литературе чего-либо подобного я не встречал, полагаю, что разговоры об изменившейся норме преждевременны.

Что там у Ожегова и Кузнецова - это надо десять раз подумать, Кузнецов у нас известный "новатор", но это пока никак не аргумент в споре о согласовании/управлении. 

Я в тексте ответа дам ссылки на слкды былых споров.

Comment: К чему так много слов, если можно сказать коротко? 

> При употреблении во множественном числе слова тысяча, миллион, миллиард имеют значение счетных существительных и потому **во всех падежах управляют родительным падежом** множественного числа (о тысячах, миллионах жителей). (Валгина)

Answer (score 4):

*Тысяча* - это существительное и склоняется, как существительное первого склонения. **Тысяча рублей** - словосочетание сущ.+сущ. Просклоняйте любое подобное словосочетание: *ученик школы, улица города* и т. д. Зависимое существительное не изменяется. А со времен Пушкина 200 лет прошло. Не напишем же мы "в постел**е**".