# С тысячей человек(ами)?

Tags: согласование

Доброго времени суток! Спасибо за ответы про метр с половиной.
У меня ещё похожий вопрос. Как правильно, с двумя тысячами человек или человеками?  
Я думаю, что человек, а мне говорят, что человеками. Очень странно.
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 4):

Норма:С двумя тысячами человек.

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html

В особую часть речи – имя числительное – выделяются только те количественные и собирательные слова, которые обладают своими собственными морфологическими признаками, не позволяющими объединить их ни с существительными, ни с прилагательными. Тысяча, тысячи, тысяче,тысячу,тысячей, о тысяче повторяют 1 склонение сущ.(каша, каши, к каше, кашу, кашей, о каше).Значит,это существительное. Существительные, лексически обозначающие число или количество кого-чего-н., во всех падежах управляют существительным, называющим считаемые предметы. Тысяча чего? С тысячей чего? -управление.:

Тысяча человек, тысячей (и тысячью)человек (и человеками), тысячей (и тысячью) рублей (и рублями); о тысяче человек; миллион книг, миллионом книг.

Как видим, в творительном падеже появляется форма Тысячью человеками - это числительное.Она возможна только без определения (НО:каждой тысячей человек, одной тысячей человек, двумя тысячами человек)Разберём предложение: Я вернусь с двумя тысячами человек. Я вернусь с кем?- с тысячами человек.Сколькими тысячами?-двумя.-определение.(но не так: Я вернусь с кем?- с человеками. Сколькими?- двумя тысячами)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно "с двумя тысячами человек". Проверяем: тысяча человек, две тысячи человек, с двумя тысячами человек и т.д. Так что правы вы :)

Comment: Надюшка, а как вы **проверили**?  
Сто человек, двести человек, со ста человеками, с двумястами человек(ами)?.
Аналогии вообще очень скользкая вещь, а тут они не просто не работают, их нет в **принципе**, это могут быть разные части речи.

Comment: Согласна, подбор и аналогия  вряд ли прояснят ситуацию. Но сказать "с двумя тысячами человекОВ" у меня язык не поворачивается.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что пока еще правильно все-таки "с двумя тысячами человеками".

Посмотрите здесь.

[5000 рублей/рублями?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13658/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-5000-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

*Это не совсем повтор, поскольку тут дело осложняется еще и тем, что человек имеет иррегулярную форму множественного числа: люди. А "человек" используется только в сочетании с числительными. И вместе с тем не является счетной формой, ибо имеет другие падежные формы: с пятью человеками*.

С другой стороны, не могу не признать, что сочетание "с (одной) тысячей человеками" (которое у вас в вопросе) выглядит совсем уж дико.  "С пятью человеками" - никуда не денешься. разумеется, когда "одна тысяча" - тут числительное, а не условное обозначение численности по образу "сотня" или "дюжина"; тысяча может выступать и в таком качестве, например в казачьих войсках.

//================
Справка, однако, совсем запуталась....
http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_92
Я не о том, что она несколько раз меняла мнение.
Но теперь по "Письмовнику" получается "(одной) тысячей человек", но "тысячью человеками".
Вроде бы, всё наоборот, поскольку "тысячей" - числительное, "тысячью" - существительное, нет???

Comment: Да нет, не запуталась:с тысячей - сущ. - как с чашей; с тысячью - числит.-как с пятью, шестью,семью, восемью(восьмью)."Одной тысячей человек" -сущ., "тысячью человеками" - числит..

Comment: Людмила, простите, не понял.
В "одна тысяча пять человек" слово *тысяча* - числительное? 
Тогда, если следовать Вашему пониманию, получается "с одной **тысячью** пятью"? Никогда бы не сказал.   
А вот варианты типа "Атиаман с одной тысяч**ью** пошел лесом, а Такойто Имяреков с другой тысяч**ью** - логом" вполне слыхивал. Это ошибка?

Comment: В составное числительное иногда входит существительное тысяча. Тысяча - всегда существительное(по форме), кроме творительного падежа. Там 2 варианта: с определением - сущ., без определения - числит. Нормативно: Атаман с одной тысячей(с кем?-тысячей,какой? сколькими?-одной, двумя и т.д.-определение).С одной тысячью-разговорный вариант.Так что С тысячью пятью - числит., а С одной тысячей пятью "тысячей" - сущ.

Comment: Спасибо, хотя моих мозгов уже не хватает...

Ладно, подождем очередной смены курса. )))

А, да!

*Со ста человеками*, но *с двумястами человек*? Так?
Получается, сто - числительное, двести - существительное?  
Разберешься тут...(((

Comment: И двести - числительное, только образованное сращением(две съти(ять)им.пад.двойств.ч.), триста=три ста(им.п. мн.ч.)Надо же учитывать историю слов.Кстати, в др.-р. сорок, девяносто, сто склонялись как существительные. Остатки у Радищева: Во сте саженях стоял господский двор.Аксаков: По сту тысяч.Может, поэтому и "пятьюстами"(как пятью нотами). Я учу своих детей так проверять склонение сотен, чтобы не ошибиться:пятисот-пяти нот, о пятистах-о пяти нотах

Comment: Людмила, да я понимаю, что двести числительное. И образование его знаю.
Только в таком случае надо правило уточнять. А то не стыкуется одно с другим.

Comment: Правило есть .  О «тысяче»§ 1367  -примечание , о склонении числ.«сто»§ 1373. 
http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html   только в школьных учебниках нет, видимо, считают лишним загромождением мозгов. Кому надо - найдут.

Comment: Да я не про школу, Вы же знаете, мне важно до сути докопаться, а уж то, как школьникам преподать,

Параграф этот в АГ я, разумеется, видел, даже ссылался на него неоднократно (может, не здесь). Что-то мне там показалось недоговоренным или не соответвубщим истине, не помню сейчас. Ладне, перечитаю. Спасибо.