# К 10 000 покупателям или к 10 000 покупателей?

Tags: числительные

Грамота дает такие ответы:

1. Как правильно написать:
   "...Откроет свои двери 10 000 посетите-лям /-лей"? И почему? Как правильно с числительными, когда они пишутся цифрами?
   Кажется, "десяти тысячам посетителей"? Но когда написано цифрами - как-то странно выглядит, а "откроет свои двери 10 000 посетителям" тоже странно.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Правильно: 10 000 посетителей (десяти тысячам посетителей). В подобном примере, возможно, лучше употребить словесную форму чисел.

2. Как правильно: Каждый нейрон соединен с 10 000 других нейронов или Каждый нейрон соединен с 10 000 другими нейронами? Имеет ли значение, как написано 10 000, — цифрами или словами? 
   Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Верно: *другими нейронами* — при обеих формах написания, цифрами и буквами.

Какой ответ правильный?

Comment: А ссылку на эти ответы можете добавить в вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Да, действительно, существует такой ответ:

> http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE&start=15

Мне он показался некорректным, а может быть, несколько устаревшим. Поискала ещё похожие вопросы, нашла:

> Вопрос с сайта  Грамма.ру: Вопрос 7600: На сайте gramota.ru бросилось
>   в глаза: "Ответьте, пожалуйста, как правильно: "Сумма,  эквивалентная
>   ста тысячам долларам" или "... долларов"? Ответ справочной службы
>   русского  языка: "Правильный первый вариант".  Вопрос: "Обьясните
>   пожалуйста, почему в вопросе № 215030 вы ответили именно так. А
>   именно,  почему правильно говорить "...эквивалентно пяти тысячам
>   долларАМ", а не "...эквивалетно пяти  тысячам долларОВ..."?" Ответ
>   справочной службы русского языка: Слово тысяча здесь –  не
>   существительное (которое управляет существительным доллар, требуя
>   родительного падежа),  а числительное, которое согласуется с
>   существительным. Ср.: эквивалентно пяти долларам,  пятидесяти
>   долларам, ста долларам, аналогично пяти тысячам долларам".  НЕУЖЕЛИ
>   ВАШИ КОЛЛЕГИ ПРАВЫ?!
>
> Ответ: Наши коллеги правы, но лишь отчасти. Точнее было бы сказать,
>   что они "не неправы".  Вопрос об употреблении слова "тысяча" **является
>   дискуссионным и недостаточно выясненным**.  В свое время Н.М. Карамзин
>   писал: "Где же узнаете, как должно писать: с двумя стами Гранадер  или
>   Гранадерами, с двумя тысячами рублей или рублями? Вот камень
>   преткновения! Вот узел  Гордиев!" Этот гордиев узел не разрублен до
>   сих пор, хотя со времен слов Карамзина прошло более  двух веков. Л.К.
>   Граудина называет слово "тысяча" грамматическим хамелеоном, поскольку
>   оно  ведет себя то как числительное, то как существительное. Это
>   находит свое отражение даже в  наличии двух форм тв. п. ед. ч. -
>   "тысячей" и "тысячью" (вторая форма употребляется в составе 
>   количественных оборотов и образована по модели числительных - "пятью",
>   "десятью" и пр.).  Двойственность грамматической природы слова
>   "тысяча" проявляется и на уровне его сочетаемости  в составе
>   количественных оборотов. Утверждается, что слово "тысяча" в функции
>   числительного  согласуется с существительным, а в функции счетного
>   существительного управляет  существительным. Собственно, **в ответе,
>   данном на сайте gramota.ru, исходят из этой позиции:  "тысяча" в
>   словосочетании "сто тысяч долларов" - это числительное, следовательно,
>   во всех падежах, кроме им. п. и отчасти вин. п., оно согласуется с
>   существительным, которое является главным. Тем не менее, как
>   утверждает  Д.Э. Розенталь, "во множественном числе слово тысяча, как
>   правило, употребляется в значении  счетного существительного и
>   управляет связанным с ним словом: город с двумя тысячами жителей".
>   Таким образом, словосочетания "ста тысячам долларов" и "пяти тысячам
>   долларов" нельзя счесть "неправильными"**. В целом же  хочется еще раз
>   подчеркнуть, что особенности сочетаемости слова "тысяча" не вполне
>   выяснены и  недостаточно описаны. Как нам быть, если у профессионалов
>   такие расхождения?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:

> Должны сказать, что это достаточно старый и не вполне корректный ответ
>   "Справочного бюро". С тех пор мы неоднократно говорили о неточности в
>   наших рассуждениях на эту тему. Более того, в рубрике "Письмовник"
>   была опубликована статья, проясняющая данный вопрос. Пожалуйста,
>   воспользуйтесь ссылкой:
>   http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_92
>   № 232798  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE&start=30

Прохожу по ссылке:

> Однако одновременно с формой творительного падежа существительного
>   тысячей существует форма числительного – тысячью,  в сочетании с
>   которой согласование и управление конкурируют. **Согласование возможно
>   только в том случае, если слово тысяча обозначает точное число и не
>   имеет при себе определения: с тысячью студентами, с тысячью знакомыми,
>   с тысячью рублями в кармане.** Форма тысячью также может обозначать
>   неопределенно большое количество чего-либо, в этом случае вместо
>   согласования требуется управление: человек с тысячью лиц, в кабинете
>   все заполнено тысячью бумаг; Воздух был наполнен тысячью разных
>   птичьих свистов (Гоголь); тысячью буйных и огненных голов (Л.
>   Андреев), тысячью мелких уколов (Короленко). Правильно: тысяче
>   работников, миллиону работников, трем тысячам работников (д. п.),
>   тысячей работников, миллионом работников, тремя тысячами работников,
>   тысячью работниками и одной тысячей работников (т. п.). Правильно:
>   **обратиться к двадцати пяти тысячам студентов, но обратиться к двадцати**
>   **пяти тысячам ста студентам.**

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/61-rubric-92

Получается, что корректно управление: *Каждый нейрон соединен с 10 000 других нейронов*, потому что, во-первых, **при употреблении во множественном числе слова тысяча, миллион, миллиард имеют значение счетных существительных и потому во всех падежах управляют родительным падежом множественного числа,** во-вторых, у нас **есть определение, следовательно, согласование невозможно.**

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта пока ещё правильны. Вариант ***"к 10 000 покупателям"*** устаревает, хотя исторически был единственно возможным. Вариант - ***"к 10 000 покупателей"*** - современная норма, активно вытесняющая старую.

Этот вопрос давно поднимался и каждый раз всплывает снова:
[С тысячей человек(ами)?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19300)
[5000 рублей/рублями?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13658)

Перетащу оттуда примеры, которые не укладывается в изложенную Людмилой схему.

> "Нам надо средств-с, средств прежде всего, и вот, после долгих споров,
>   порешено у него с отцом на ***последних шести тысячах рублях***, и их ему
>   высылают."

(Достоевский, "Братья Карамазовы")

> Тут был француз К. М., женатый
>   На кукле чахлой и горбатой
>   ***И семи тысячах душах***.

(Пушкин "Евгений Онегин", 8, XXV)

Повторю кратко. Согласовательная норма (*на шести тысячах рублях, на семи тысячах душах, к десяти тысячам покупателям*) пока ещё нормативна, но вытесняется управлением (н*а шести тысячах рублей, на семи тысячах душ, к десяти тысячам покупателей*). 
Остальное - см. по ссылкам выше, там же я давал и свои ссылки на дискуссии, материала больше чем достаточно.

И маленькое замечание. При всем уважении к авторам текстов, процитированных Людмилой, не могу не заметить, что они перемудрили. Так, привлечение другого значения слова "тысяча" (которое порождает в творительном форму "тысячью") для объяснения конкурирующих форм управления-согласования только путает и ничего не объясняет. Примеры из классики - уж точно.