# Как правильно писать: говорил на тысяч(е/ах) язык(ах/ов)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Как правильно писать: говорил на тысяч(е/ах) язык(ах/ов)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это условное преувеличение, поэтому "на тысяче языков". "На тысяч**ах**" воспринималось бы излишне реалистично - как попытка указать приблизительное количество.

P.S. Почему не "язык**ах**": тысяча здесь является существительным (форму числительного оно может принимать только в творительном падеже) и выступает синонимом таких слов как "уйма" или "множество", с которыми такое окончание явно невозможно. Похожий смысл существительного (с теми же последствиями для склонения) можно придать и меньшим количествам, заменяя сто "сотней", десять "десятком", пять "пятёркой" и т.п.

Comment: Alex_ander, это абсолютно правильный ответ, но если нетрудно, опишите подробно. В таком виде понять Ваш ответ - нужна некоторая подготовка, которой явно недостает большинству участников.  Это вообще больная тема, надо привлечь внимание. Поясните прежде всего, в чем разница между "одной тысячей" и "тысячей" просто. И еще то, что происходит сейчас ("тысяча" становится не как "сто", но как "миллион"). Если не сможете, я сам напишу попозже, но не хочу у Вас хлеб отбивать.

Comment: Все-таки мне придется Вас дополнить...  Вы сознательно или нет, не раскрываете грамматику. То, что Вы говорите, только начало рассуждений. А если здесь не синоним множества, а именно числительное? Примерное или точное. "В информационной базе содержится сведения о тысяче языках/языков"? "Разработчики ограничили справочник тысячью языков/языками"?

Comment: Сведения о тысяче языков (во всех вариантах), ограничили тысячью языками (точным числом), владел тысячей/тысячью языков. Разные варианты (в зависимости от трактовки количества) возможны только с формой творительного падежа "тысячью" (числительное). В остальных случаях "тысяча" - существительное.

Comment: Нет. С творительным падежом действительно путаница самая большая (формы тысячей-тысячью). Но и без него хватает заморочек. Посмотрите классические тексты.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: ( на чем? - предлож.пад.)на тысяче язык**ах,**  (а не на чего; род.падеж) -  языков.

Comment: Серж, а вы можете указать источник, что именно так? Я крепко сомневаюсь...

Comment: Серж, а на чем вы основываете свое утверждение?

Comment: А вы считаете, что  ов - это окончание предложного падежа? Нет чего - языков.Вы же не скажете, говорить на 5 языков.

Comment: Боже избави. Я вас спрашиваю про грамматику, почему вы вместо управления предлагает согласование в падеже. А не про названия падежей.  А вы, значит, скажете **"Я  говорю на миллионе языках?"**

Answer (score 0):

Вне контекста возможны все четыре варианта, но означать они будут разные вещи.

1) говорил на тысяче языков - кто-то говорил на одной тысяче языков
2) говорил на тысячах языков - кто-то говорил на нескольких тысячах языков
3) говорил на тысяче языках - кто-то говорил, стоя на куче из одной тысячи языков (орган тела)
4)  говорил на тысячах языках - кто-то говорил, стоя на куче из нескольких тысяч языков (орган тела)

Comment: Забавно, особенно последнее, хотя и спорно. Грамматика, сомнительна. Но вопрос не в этом. . Сравните: *кошелек со ста рублями*, но *кошелек с миллионом рублей*, *говорил на **ста языках***, но *на **миллионе языков***. Вопрос, по какому правилу "работает" числительное тысяча.

Comment: @behemothus "кошелёк с миллионами рублей" тоже вполне возможен (это будет означать, что в кошельке 2 и более миллиона рублей).

Comment: Sarge Borsch, это не по теме.  Вы не поняли предмет обсуждения. С (двумя) миллионами рублей или двумя миллионами рублями.

Answer (score 0):

Я  уже отвечал на сходный вопрос.
И дал почти почти полный обзор грамматики числительного "тысяча" - на примере "тысячи рублей"

[5000 рублей/рублями?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13658/5000-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Не буду сюда переносить, посмотрите там хотя бы примеры. 
Смысл в том, что по происхождение и по исторической грамматике слово "тысяча" является прилагательным, как и все "мелкие" числительные. Поэтому идет согласование в падежах:  *[говорил на] пяти, десяти, тысяче языках*. Но дальнейшие числительные по происхождению уже существительные. И вместо согласования идет управление падежом: *[говорил на] миллионе языков*. При этом современные тенденции таковы, что как минимум в разговорной речи свлово "тысяча" мигрирует от своей исторической грамматики к более крупным - миллиону, миллиарду и т.д., становясь тем самым существительным. Процесс далеко еще не завершен, поэтому форму "на тысяче языков" нельзя пока назвать универсальной в отношении числительного. В том же случае, когда тысяча - существительное (со значением "много"), понятно, что управление такое же: "на тысяче языков". Видимо, именно этот факт и стал причиной перенесения падежного управления на "тысячу" как числительное.

Изложение особенностей употребления творительного падежа и сложностей при определении грамматической роли тысячи (из-за отсутствие специальной парной формы, подобной пять-пяток, десять-десяток, сто-сотня) опускаю, смю по ссылке.
Кратко отвечаю только на вопрос.

> Как правильно писать: говорил на тысяч(е/ах) язык(ах/ов)?

Здесь, как совершенно верно сказано, "на тысяче языков" является стилистически нейтральным и предпочтительным вариантом, если не имеется в виду реальная тысяча. 
Вот если там примерная тысяча или даже по-бухгалтерски точная (почему бы и нет? Компьютер или там роман фантастический), то возникают варианты. 
*На тысяче языков* и *на тысяче языках* - возможны и синонимичны, но первая сейчас преобладает в разгововрной речи, вытесняя вторую, исторически правильную.

Answer (score -1):

Считаю, что возможен вариант "говорил на тысяче языков", если речь идёт о тысяче и не более. Или - "говорил на тысячах языков", если речь идёт о многих тысячах.