# Сочетание слова "около" с числительным в косвенных падежах

Tags: склонение

Корректны ли следующие сочетания:

1.Около трёмстам тысячам москвичей;
2. Около тремястами тысячами москвичей;
3. На около трёхстах тысячах москвичей?

Comment: Могу я поинтересоваться, вы правда полагаете, что "около трехстами тысячами" - это русский язык?

Answer (score 1):

*Около* — предлог с род. п.

1. Употребляется при обозначении примерной, приблизительной величины, протяженности, длительности и т. п. чего-л.

— Так ты женат! не знал я ране! Давно ли? — Около двух лет. Пушкин, Евгений Онегин.

— В прошедшем месяце на один стол вышло около полуторы тысячи рублей. И. Гончаров, Обыкновенная история.

2. При обозначении времени, незадолго до которого, близко к которому происходит действие.

Около семи часов вечера я гулял на бульваре. Лермонтов, Княжна Мери.

Я сидел в березовой роще осенью, около половины сентября. Тургенев, Свидание.

Около полуночи бабушка ласково разбудила меня. М. Горький, В людях.

Словарь четко дает указание на падеж, поэтому ваши сочетания невозможны.

Малый академический словарь. — М.: Институт русского языка Академии наук СССР. Евгеньева А. П.

Answer (score 1):

Довольно сложные ответы получились, я упрощу: "около" в данном значении - это предлог, и этот предлог сочетается только с родительным падежом. В приведенных примерах падежи дательный, творительный, предложный. Значит, тут его употребить нельзя. Вместо него можно использовать наречия "почти", "примерно", у которых таких ограничений по сочетаемости нет.

Answer (score -1):

> 1.Около трёмстам тысячам москвичей;

Нет, неправильно. Самое мягкое, что можно сказать - некорректная замена "примерно" на около.

> 2. Около трехстами тысячами москвичей;

Это вообще ни в какие ворота не лезет.
Просклоняйте "триста тысяч москвичей" - без "около" даже.

> 3. На около трёхстах тысячах москвичей?

Нет. см. 1.

ЗЫ
Вопрос вообще-то совершенно бессодержательный, отвечать бы не стал, но одна вещь внимание привлекла. 
До относительно недавнего времени в качестве синтаксической связи числительного "тысяча" в формах "две, три, сто, пятьсот и т.д. тысяч" с существительным использовалось согласования: "с двумя тысячами рублями"[5000 рублей/рублями?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13658)

То, что мы имеем сейчас, дает повод воспринимать ту норму чуть ли не как порчу языка даже весьма взвешенными и эрудированными авторами, а примеры из Пушкина воспринимаются с недоверием (см. там же).

Я это вспомнил потому, что, заменив упомянутое согласование управлением, грамматика, видимо, дала некую лазейку для появления и этих ужастиков "около трехстами". Другого объяснения их появления в речи носителей русского как родного я не не могу представить.